# mysql convert rows to columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two columns:`client_id` and `invoice_id`. For every `client id` there can be multiple invoice ids. I am searching for a MySQL query that converts the rows of the aforementioned table into columns. I only need the first two invoices for each client. Something like the pseudo-code below:

```
SELECT ci.client_id, 
  first(ci.invoice_id) AS invoice_column1, 
  second(ci.invoice_id) AS invoice_column2
FROM client_invoices ci
GROUP BY ci.client_id
```

Sample data for client_invoices

```
client_id | invoice_id 
1           45
2           56
1           88
```

sample output

```
client_id | invoice_column1 | invoice_column2
1           45                88
2           56                NULL
```

Comment: Not exactly what you need, but have you looked into `group_concat` and `group_concat_max_len`?

Comment: How do you define first two invoices? Show some sample data and expected result to be more clear.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the desired result?

Comment: I dont care about the order since I don't expect more than two rows for each client. group_concat could be a possible solution in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to assign a row number by group and then transforms the data into columns:

```
select client_id,
  max(case when group_row_number = 1 then invoice_id end) Invoice1,
  max(case when group_row_number = 2 then invoice_id end) Invoice2
from
(
  select client_id, invoice_id,
    @num := if(@client_id = `client_id`, @num + 1, 1) as group_row_number,
    @client_id := `client_id` as dummy, overall_row_num
  from
  (
    select client_id, invoice_id, @rn:=@rn+1 overall_row_num
    from client_invoices, (SELECT @rn:=0) r
  ) x
  order by client_id, overall_row_num
) src
group by client_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/703a3/5)

Or a simpler way of doing it:

```
select client_id, 
  max(case when rownum = 1 then invoice_id end) Invoice1,
  max(case when rownum = 2 then invoice_id end) Invoice2 
from 
(
  select client_id,
    invoice_id,
    @row:=if(@prev=client_id,@row,0) + 1 as rownum,
    @prev:=client_id 
  from client_invoices
  order by client_id
)src
group by client_id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/703a3/8)

Both produce the result:

```
| CLIENT_ID | INVOICE1 | INVOICE2 |
-----------------------------------
|         1 |       45 |       88 |
|         2 |       56 |   (null) |
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a single table with multiple entries for each client the expected query should look like this.

```
SELECT
    ci.client_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ci.invoice_id) as InvoiceIds
FROM(
    SELECT
        client_id,
        invoice_id,
        @num := if(@group = client_id, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
        @group := client_id as dummy                
    FROM    client_invoices
    GROUP BY client_id , invoice_id
    HAVING row_number <= 2  
) as ci
GROUP BY ci.client_id
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
DECLARE tmp int(11);
DECLARE tmp2 int(11);
SELECT invoice_id INTO tmp FROM ci LIMIT 1,1;
SELECT invoice_id INTO tmp2 FROM ci LIMIT 2,1;
SELECT ci.client_id, 
 tmp AS invoice_column1, 
 tmp2 AS invoice_column2
 FROM client_invoices ci
 GROUP BY ci.client_id
```